# Laravel Gate User parameter with eager loading relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, authorization

As far as i know, the $user paramater on Laravel's Gate by default will returning instance of user credentials object which came from EloquentServiceProvider (not from User Model).

```
Gate::define('create-something', function ($user) {
   // Code
}
```

But, how to add **eager loading** of relationship on it ? Lets say i have relationship called stuff on User Model, so i want to access it like so :

```
Gate::define('create-something', function ($user) {
   dd($user->stuff);
}
```

Maybe easiest solution is by passing another parameters which came from Models\User , but it seems duplicating/redundant considering the $user parameter already there by default.
Is the another way to achieve this ?

**Add notes : Stuff is many to many relationship**

Comment: If `$user` is an instance of your `User.php` model, then `$user->stuff` should actually work just fine, assuming you have an accessor `getStuffAttribute()` or a relationship `public function stuff()`. What happens with your code currently?

Comment: @TimLewis sorry if my question didn't clear enough, i edit my question, what i want to achieve is actually eager loading of relationship from the instance of auth EloquentServiceProvider

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
Gate::define('create-something', function ($user) {
   $user->load('stuff');
   dd($user->stuff);
}
```

Comment: This actually works, but it will increase the query, i think that the sections relationship can be automatically loaded when the object passed to the parameters